# flutter navigate back to selected page

Tags: flutter

I have a application with contains a bottom navigation that when the app loads it defaults to the first page. If I were to click onto the second page and then from the second page, I navigate to another separate page that is not linked to the bottom navigation bar. When I click the back button in the Appbar in this page, I am take to page one again instead of page 2.

**Navigation Controller:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../pages/TaxCalcPage.dart';
import '../pages/TaxInfoPage.dart';
import '../pages/SettingsPage.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarControllerState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarControllerState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarControllerState extends State<BottomNavigationBarController> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    TaxCalcPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
    ),
    TaxInfoPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page2'),
    ),
    SettingsPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page3'),
    )
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Tax Calculators')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.info), title: Text('Tax Information')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_selectedIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Page:**

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
          iconSize: (0.06 * ratio) * width,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationBarController()), (Route route) => route == null),
        );
      },
    ),
```

So when I navigate back using the icon in the AppBar. I will take me to page 1 instead of Page 2

Answer (score 11):

Using `Navigator.of(context).pop();` should bring you back to the previous Screen with the correct State. For a better understanding of it check out this article: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

IF this does not work you have to save the current index of your `BottomNavigationBar` and pass it back to your Navigation Controller once going back to it.

Comment: When I use `Navigator.of(context).pop();` all I get is a black screen. Im not sure how to do the latter.

Comment: How do you navigate to the second page? Using `Navigator.popAndRemoveUntil(...);` will remove Pages from the Stack and you might not could go back to it using `pop()` . Reading the Medium Article I linked in my answer will help you to understand what I mean!

Comment: use pushNamed(context,"routes") instead of use.pushReplacementNamed(context,"routes")